# SQL query returning timestamp attached with a date only column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get date from a column which has its datatype set as `date` and in SQL Server the column also contains only date but when i run query from my application `C#`:

```
resultData[i][3] = sqlRdr["addedOn"].ToString();
```

It gives me a default time signature attached to it

```
select addedOn from sitrep;
```

I also tried using below cast but still same results:

```
select Convert(Date, Convert(datetime, addedOn)) as addedOn from sitrep;
```

Comment: What is "default time signature"?

Answer (score 2):

If your saving it to a string i would try.

```
Convert.ToDateTime(sqlRdr["addedOn"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query as:

```
resultData[i][3] = sqlRdr["addedOn"].ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```